# DataTables and ColumnFilter with percentage column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I've added percent column to my datatable using below code:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "percent-pre": function (a) {
        var x = (a == "-") ? 0 : a.replace(/%/, "");
        return parseFloat(x);
    },

    "percent-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "percent-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

This way I can sort column that has '%'.

I also added ColumnFilter plugin ([Plugin Link](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn-history/r73/trunk/index.html)) to my table to be able to filter individual columns.

When I save and display percentage value as numeric I'm able to filter that column:
[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/LVSZF/)

But when I set that column type to percentage and try to filter same column I always get empty data:
[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/5pbP7/)

Open first fiddle and click 'Load data' and try to set range for '%' column - everything is working. Now do the same with second one - You'll get empty table.

How can I apply range filter to column with percent values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out it is quite easy.
Store percent value as numeric and declare column as follows:

```
{
    sTitle: "%",
    sType: "numeric",
    sWidth: "40px",
    sClass: "center",
    mData: "percent",
    mRender: function (data, type, full) {
        if (type === 'display') {//this is available in DataTables 1.9+
            return data + ' %';
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

This is my updated and working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/5pbP7/22/)